# Made a method Delete1 keeps recursiving

Tags: prolog

I'm initiated on Prolog and I'm having an issue on a method. I made Delete1 method to delete a certain position on a list. I also made a Try method that uses the Delete method, and when Try fails on a comprobation it goes back to Delete instead of searching for another "entrances"on try method

```
delete1([H|T],0,L):-
    L = T.
delete1([H|T],N,[H1|T1]):-
    dec(N,N1),
    H1 = H,
    delete1(T,N1,T1),
    conc([H1],T1,L).

try(J,K,L):-
    delete1(J,K,L1),
    comp(J,L1). #HERE

try(J,K,L):- #HERE1
    print("ALOHA").
```

So, `dec(N,N1)` decrements `N` by one and stores it in `N1`, `comp(J,L1)` compares the 2 list and returns false or true. They both seem to work fine (checked separately). The problem is on #HERE, when it returns false instead of getting in #HERE1 it goes back to `delete1`. Can anybody give some light on this.
By the way, this is my 1st post and i must than this community because it has helped me a lot through the degree. Sorry for my English, I'm Spanish
Thank you very much

Comment: You definitely need an `N > 0` constraint in your second `delete1/3` clause. Otherwise, it can keep going with negative values of the index. What's the purpose/need for `conc([H1], T1, L)`? You aren't using `L` here, and your `[H1|T1]` in the head of your clause already provides what you need as a result.

Comment: Could you also please indicate exactly what query you entered that gave you the results you weren't expecting? I assume it was some kind of query on `try(...)`.

Comment: As an aside, you can replace `delete1([H|T],0,L):-
    L = T.` with `delete1([H|T], 0, T).` and `delete1([H|T],N,[H1|T1]):-
    dec(N,N1),
    H1 = H, ...` with `delete1([H|T],N,[H|T1]):- N > 0,
    dec(N,N1), ...`

Comment: Hello there, thats was defently what i needed. Thanks for the advise of not using conc. Thats it, i was making queries as try([a,b,c,d],2,L) just to check the delette1 method.

Comment: Thank you again for your support, i think its neccesary to say that these communities keep going on because of people like you. From now on, i will stop lurking, despite of your name :). Thank you again!!!

Comment: @coder: Question neither specific to SWI nor ISO.

Comment: @false, right! I just think that all questions have to do with ISO Prolog, (clearly the question had nothing to do with SWI) so that's why didn't remove ISO but on the other hand doesn't ask specific for ISO so you have right ,thanks for the notice!!

Comment: Hello again!, sorry, I am not sure of the difference between SWI and ISO.

Comment: I am writing again, because even with the modifications that @lurker made with the code, when I use delete1 in another method, and Immediately do a comprobation onn something, if this comprobation returns false, the "ejecutation thread" comes back to the delete1 method:

Comment: usame2(J,K):-
    delete1(J,K,R),
    K == 3.
usame2(J,K):-
    print(":mother").

Comment: delete1([H|T],0,T).
delete1([H|T],N,[H1|T1]):-
    N>0,
    dec(N,N1),
    H1 = H,
    delete1(T,N1,T1).

Comment: So if I trace it calling usame2([a,b,c,d,e],2). When it does the comprobation K == 3 and rturns false, i dont know why the trace goes back to delete1

Comment: Please don't add code updates in comments. Very hard to read. If you need to update your question, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44069034/edit) the question using the link provided. Any other explanations or queries that didn't work, add them to the question as well. And what do you mean by *comprobation*?

Comment: Sorry, didnt know that rule, I will keep it on mind.

Comment: I mean that it checks if K == 3 which in the call i did of usame2 K is 2 so it should return false.

Comment: And when it does returns false the ejecutation pipe goes back to delete1